# extract total hours in a particular MONTH and YEAR, taking into account leap years, using PHP

Tags: php

I need to extract the total hours in a any month, given just the MONTH and the YEAR, taking into account leap years.

Here is my code so far...

```
$MonthName = "January";
$Year = "2013";

$TimestampofMonth = strtotime("$MonthName  $Year");
$TotalMinutesinMonth = $TimestampofMonth / 60     // to convert to minutes
$TotalHoursinMonth = $TotalMinutesinMonth / 60    // to convert to hours
```

Comment: Get the timestamp of the first day of the next month the timestamp of the first day of this current month and substract.

Comment: Do you need to allow for changes in daylight savings that occur during the month?

Comment: @MarkBaker No. not really.

Comment: Upgrade PHP and use the DateTime object...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<?php
$MonthName = "January";
$Year = "2013";
$days = date("t", strtotime("$MonthName 1st, $Year"));
echo $days * 24;
```

Comment: Is this going to end well with DST?

Comment: sorry buddy , i only have MONTH and YEAR.

Comment: then set the default day to `01`, it doesn't matter what the day is as long as it is valid.

Comment: @RyanNaddy what do you mean bro?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 Not everywhere has daylight savings, such as places in Arizona. About 50% of the world doesn't have DST: http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/g.html

Comment: I know that. Neither does UTC. Just added the comment because I thought of it and this will be screwed up for OP if he wants to account for DST. This can easily be fixed by adding another check for `I`.

Answer (score 1):

Just work out the number of days in the month and then multiply by 24, like so:

```
// Set the date in any format
$date = '01/01/2013';
// another possible format etc...
$date = 'January 1st, 2013';

// Get the number of days in the month
$days = date('t', strtotime($date));

// Write out the days
echo $days;
```

Comment: Thank you @lloyd, dont forget to accept your final answer though :-)

Comment: @lloyd Do you know how to?

Comment: yah i think so. i just click the "UP" arrow to the left of the best post right? I just noted that your contribution and Ryan Naddy's are exactly the same.

Comment: Give @Ryan the credit as he got their first I think. Click the tick next to the answer to accept. The upvote is just a way to say this answer is good and thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` since you don't have day

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("F Y", "January 2013");
printf("%s hr(s)",$date->format("t") * 24);
```

Well if you are looking at working day its a different approach

```
$date = "January 2013"; // You only know Month and year
$workHours = 10; // 10hurs a day

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat("F Y d", "$date 1"); // added first
printf("%s hr(s)", $start->format("t") * 24);

// if you are only looking at working days

$end = clone $start;
$end->modify(sprintf("+%d day", $start->format("t") - 1));

$interval = new DateInterval("P1D"); // Interval
var_dump($start, $end);

$hr = 0;
foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end) as $day) {  
    // Exclude sarturday & Sunday
    if ($day->format('N') < 6) {
        $hr += $workHours; // add working hours
    }
}
printf("%s hr(s)", $hr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function get_days_in_month($month, $year)
{
  return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year %400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31);
}

$month = 4;
$year = 2013;

$total_hours = 24 * get_days_in_month($month, $year);


?>
```

you can use above function to retrieve total days in a month taking into account leap year and then multiply the value to 24
plus, you can also use a cal_days_in_month function but it only supports PHP builds of PHP 4.0.7 and higher.

---

and if you are using the above "get_day_in_month" then you need to parse the string into integer which can be done like this

FOR MONTH
`<?php
  $date = date_parse('July');
  $month_int = $date['month'];
?>`

FOR YEAR
`<?php
  $year_string = "2013"
  $year_int = (int) $year_string
?>`